# Rails 3 app with Devise loading existing users

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

We've built a new app which involves a lengthly registration process. We're using Rails 3 and devise for authentication using :confirmable.

Now we've got to import a large set of existing users from an old system. We want this to be done manually to test the process.

So the problem is we don't want to send confirmation emails to these users.

Any suggestions how we can either suppress emails and still manually complete the registration process?

Dom

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the `confirmable` source code, it seems as if it won't send out any emails if the user is set to confirmed on create.

First off, you need to determine whether you want the newly created user to get an email or not. I'd suggest adding a checkbox to the form, or alternatively cross-referencing the email address against the old users table:

```
def create 
  # Form style
  skip_email? = params[:user].delete(:skip_email)

  # Old users style
  skip_email? = !!OldUser.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])

  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  ...
end
```

Assuming you've done one of the two, you'll have a boolean value of `skip_email?`. Now you can do:

```
def create 
  skip_email? = true # See above

  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  @user.skip_confirmation!

  if @user.save
    ...
  end
end
```

`skip_confirmation!` is a method Devise adds to the User model. You can find the Devise source code [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb).